# Reverse string function not working properly

Tags: c, string, reverse

Here is my code. I just can't seem to figure it out. Sometimes i get no output, and sometimes i just get 3 random characters, regardless of how long the entered string is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char* array, int numberOfChars);

int main()
{
    char string[250];
    int length;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(string);
    printf("How long is the string:");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    reverse(string, length);
    printf("Reversed string is: %s\n"), string;

    return 0;
}

void reverse(char *userArray, int numberOfChars)
{
    char temp;
    int fromEnd = 0, fromStart = 0;

    fromEnd = numberOfChars;
    while (fromStart < fromEnd)
    {
        temp = userArray[fromStart];
        userArray[fromStart] = userArray[fromEnd];
        userArray[fromEnd] = temp;
        fromStart++;
        fromEnd--;

    }
}
```

I really dread asking these questions here but I can't seem to fix it...
Any help appreciated

Comment: should `fromEnd = numberOfChars - 1` since indexes start at 0?

Comment: Are you really going to ask the user how long the string is? The computer can do that more reliably. Unlike the user, the computer might even have fun counting the chars.

Comment: don't use variable name (string) which is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Can you give us a sample input string and length?

Comment: Also your algorithm won't work, think about what happens when you try to write to the last character (or any character past half-way)

Comment: Look closely at your `printf` call: The `string` must go inside the parantheses.

Comment: Seems the problem was that I didn't subtract 1 from the fromEnd variable.

Comment: Im not sure but I think there is a function called `strrev()`

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually you need to swap the ends until you are left with a string of length 0 or 1. You don't need to test for the length of the remaining portion of the string after each iteration however, because it can be shown that exactly `length/2` swaps will be needed.

```
void reverse (char *s)
{
    size_t length = strlen (s);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
        char tmp;

        tmp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[length - 1 - i];
        s[length - 1 - i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by indexing both from the same point. You seem to have more pointers (?) than me but the program works after i changed
   fromEnd = numberOfChars
to
   fromEnd = numberOfChars - 1

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to complicate things like that, try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char *src = "Michi";
    char dest[256];
    int i=-1,j=0;

    while(src[++i]!='\0');

    while(i>=0){
        dest[j++] = src[--i];
    }

    dest[j]='\0';
    printf("Your new string is: %s",dest);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Your new string is: ihciM
```

This is probably what you need:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void reverse(char *ptr);


int main(void) {
    char src[256] = "Michi";
    reverse(src);

    printf("Your new string is: %s",src);
    return (0);
}

void reverse(char *src){
    char dest;
    size_t i, j = 0;

    i = 0;
    j = strlen(src) - 1;

    while (i < j) {
        dest = src[i];
        src[i] = src[j];
        src[j] = dest;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does what OP asked, Should i give a complete Answer ? The OP knows now what he need to done, That's the whole point here.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `gets()`,use `fgets()`.To reverse strings,you don't need to pass number of characters,since strings in C are null-terminated.check this very simple function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(char *_Str);

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "Hello Buddy";
    reverse(str);
    printf("%s\n",str);
    return 0;
}

void reverse(char *_Str)
{
    char tmp,*_b,*_e;
    _b = _e = _Str;
    while(*_e) _e++;
    _e--;
    while(_b < _e)
    {
        tmp = *_b;
        *_b++ = *_e;
        *_e-- = tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the very important line you missed is assigning the null character. And do not take the length of your string as an input from the user. use the function `some_integer=strlen(stringname);` This will return the length of your `stringname` and assign it to `some_integer`. Your function to reverse the string should be as

```
void reverse(char *userarray) // no need of a second argument. Do not trust your users.
{
    char temp;
    int fromEnd,fromStart = 0; /
    fromEnd = strlen(userarray)-1; // here the length of your string is assigned to fromEnd.
    while (fromStart < fromEnd)
    {
        temp = userArray[fromStart];
        userArray[fromStart] = userArray[fromEnd];
        userArray[fromEnd] = temp;
        fromStart++;
        fromEnd--;
    }
    userarray[strlen(userarray)-1]='\0'; //You missed this line (very important)
}
```

And chek your `printf` statement.

It should be

`printf("Your reversed string is %s \n",string);`

not

`printf("Your reversed string is %s \n"),string;`

I belive this will work. Check it and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect code.  The needed string for the `printf()` is not in the function.    [@M Oehm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331413/reverse-string-function-not-working-properly/34343384#comment56404605_34331413)

```
/// printf("Reversed string is: %s\n"), string;
printf("Reversed string is: %s\n", string);
```

Also original code can easily wipe out the string terminating null character `'\0'`.  Better to use `strlen(string)` rather than ask the user for the length.

Likely should use `- 1` as commented by [@WalterM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331413/reverse-string-function-not-working-properly/34343384#comment56404359_34331413).   It is unclear what values OP is using.

```
// fromEnd = numberOfChars;
if (numberOfChars <= 0) return;
fromEnd = numberOfChars - 1;
```

---

Answers I have seen so far depend on `int` well addressing all elements of a string.  `size_t` is the right approach as `int` may be too small.

Many answers would fail on a string such as `""`.

So here is another contribution without those restrictions.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *str_revese_inplace(char *s) {
  char *left = s;
  char *right = s + strlen(s);
  while (right > left) {
    right--;
    char t = *right;
    *right = *left;
    *left = t;
    left++;
  }
  return s;
}

void stest(const char *s) {
  char t[strlen(s) + 1];
  // or char t[100];
  strcpy(t, s);
  printf("'%s' --> '%s'\n", s, str_revese_inplace(t));
}

int main(void) {
  stest("123");
  stest("12");
  stest("1");
  stest("");
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
'123' --> '321'
'12' --> '21'
'1' --> '1'
'' --> ''
```